# send mal with TLS / SSL

Tags: c#, email

After searching across the web i'am still confused about the correct approach to send a secure email.

I am developing a web email client interface to send mails with a different configurable smtp email servers (for example: gmail.com, outlook.office365.com,...whatever)

I use a simple SmtpClient with the EnableSsl = true, and it works with gmail and office365 (thought in the gmail i had to configure the https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to make it work).

The question is if just enabling EnableSsl to true is the only action to do for sending a secure email with net 4.5 (configuring user and password credentials too, of course), or if i have to make different configurations if the smtp server uses TLS or SSL?